# metal die charged, where do the charges go?

Tags: electrostatics

I'm puzzled by this question: I have a metal die (a regular cube, completely filled with homogeneous iron for instance); I charge it with some µCoulombs. Where do the charges go?

Can the faces of the die have some charge?

Or do they go to the eight corners?

Comment: "Loosely speaking, the bits of charge repel one another, and they move as far away from each other as possible to the outer surface." - [UCLA Physics](http://demoweb.physics.ucla.edu/content/experiment-4-van-de-graaff) They're distributed over the entire surface of the conductor no matter what the shape.

Comment: This is not true @pentane, this is only the case for spheres where the curvature is the same all over. But in general they distribute  proportional to the curvature. In an ellipsoid, for example, charges distribute more towards the more distant and pointy poles.

Answer (score 3):

They accumulate in the corners.

Free excess charges (electrons) in a conductor (metals) will move freely towards the surface until the internal electric field is zero. If this was not the case, the non-balanced field will further move them until this is the case.

But the geometry of the dice makes the faces very unstable place for charges to accumulate, since field components parallel to the faces are not balanced with stability.

So they will end up accumulating in edges where non balanced field along them will push them towards the corners equally distributed.

I made this simple graph, it should look similar to this...

[image]

---

### Expanding on why charges don't populate the faces...

Imagine 6 equal charges centered on the faces of the die, because of symmetry conditions they will be static (assuming the surface has a much larger potential and electrons cannot escape). The problem with these electrons in this positions is that is a very unstable configuration: if you move one of them by a tiny bit, all will be unbalanced and fall to the corners. However, in the corners, having three surface potentials holding them, there is no other place in the cube to fall back to, and small displacements of the electrons will not unbalance the configuration as a whole.

Comment: Could you explain the statement that "field components parallel to the faces are not balanced with stability" a bit more, maybe with a diagram?

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify that statement.

Comment: What do you mean? It would depend on the frontier conditions that you impose between the many cubes. If the charge can cries the freely then they will not fill uniformly the faces of the big cube.

Comment: Correction, above where it says "cries the freely" I meant "cross them freely"

Comment: @mhleo The charges do repel each other toward the corner, but not nearly as much as your moving picture suggests (see my calculations below).

Answer (score 0):

I created a discrete model of 56 equal charges distributed on the faces of a cube of edge length 3 as shown below

[image]

the parameter I can change is d. I computed a value proportional to the electrostatic potential energy of the distribution of charges as a function of d. The result is as follows

[image]

So the charges do repel each other slighty toward the corners.